# scp hanging sometimes

Tags: networking, file-transfer, timeout

I have an issue with data transmission from one server to another.

An example of the issue is doing `scp` to copy a file between the servers. 1 time out of 10 it just hangs, and eventually times out, with this message:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection timed out
lost connection
```

This is an example of the issue.  I am doing other things between the two servers, and it also times out.

What could be the problem?  What could I do to diagnose the issue?  Things have been working for 6 months, now suddenly today it has stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a network problem but it can be anything between the two servers, like network adapters, cables, switches or wifi.

If the servers are remotly connected through Internet, a temporary instability can cause a connection timeout.

Also you could be hitting a firewall policy.

You have to monitor the scp and when the connection timeout happens, run a mtr from one server to the other with tcp protocol to port 22, that can give you a clue.

```
mtr --tcp --port 22 your.remote.host
```

Look for a hop, from that point on, all packages are lost.